# C Linux Kernel page interfere with previous variable

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, rootkit

I want to hook `read` in linux kernel to achieve showing which process reads the file in `/home/xytao/safe` directory.

```
// get absolute file path from file struct
char *get_filename(struct file *file)
{
    char *buf = (char *)__get_free_page(GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buf)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char *filename = dentry_path_raw(file->f_path.dentry, buf, PAGE_SIZE - 1);
    if (IS_ERR(filename))
    {
        free_page((unsigned long)buf);
        return NULL;
    }
    free_page((unsigned long)buf);
    return filename;
}

asmlinkage ssize_t fake_read(int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __nbytes)
{
    char *pathname;
    struct file *file;
    struct path *path;
    struct files_struct *files = current->files;
    spin_lock(&files->file_lock);
    file = fcheck_files(files, __fd);
    if (!file)
    {
        spin_unlock(&files->file_lock);
        return -ENOENT;
    }
    spin_unlock(&files->file_lock);
    ssize_t out = real_read(__fd, __buf, __nbytes);
    pathname=get_filename(file);
    if (!strncmp(pathname, "/home/xytao/safe", 15))
    {   fm_alert("pathname_before:%s\n", pathname);
        struct file *process_file = get_task_exe_file(current);
        fm_alert("process_name:%s\n", get_filename(process_file));
        fm_alert("pathname_after:%s\n:", pathname);    
    }
    return out;
}
```

But it seems `pathname` has been changed after get the process name, and `pathname` has been compromised by `get_filename(process_file)`.

For example, after I open `/home/xytao/safe/test` , I get the following output:

```
[ 1181.179485] fsmonko.fake_read: pathname_before:/home/xytao/safe/test
[ 1181.179488] fsmonko.fake_read: process_name:/usr/bin/gedit
[ 1181.179490] fsmonko.fake_read: pathname_after:/home/x/usr/bin/gedit
           :
[ 1181.181590] fsmonko.fake_read: pathname_before:/home/xytao/safe/test
[ 1181.181594] fsmonko.fake_read: process_name:/usr/bin/gedit
[ 1181.181595] fsmonko.fake_read: pathname_after:/home/x/usr/bin/gedit
           :
[ 1181.190503] fsmonko.fake_read: pathname_before:/home/xytao/safe/test
[ 1181.190509] fsmonko.fake_read: process_name:/usr/bin/gedit
[ 1181.190511] fsmonko.fake_read: pathname_after:/home/x/usr/bin/gedit
           :
[ 1197.523906] fsmonko.fake_read: pathname_before:/home/xytao/safe/test
[ 1197.523915] fsmonko.fake_read: process_name:/usr/bin/nautilus
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`dentry_path_raw` does not allocate a filename (string) for you; it copies it into the memory buffer you provide.   When you free that page, filename has become a dangling reference.   It would be better if you took a page fault on referencing it, but there would be a performance price if `free_page` immediately updated the page mappings.

filename will point to somewhere in the middle of the buffer you provide, so you might be able to free it in the caller via:

```
free_page((uintptr_t)filename & PAGE_MASK);
```

Comment: Sorry, can you provide the code? I don't quite understand `filename will point to somewhere in the middle of the buffer you provide`

Comment: Change get_filename() to not call free_page() in the non-error case;   Have fake_read() call free_page() appropriately.   If you are hacking kernel code, you should be able to handle this.

Comment: You mean use `free_page((uintptr_t)pathname& PAGE_MASK)` in `fake_read() `?

Comment: Yes, once you are finished with the pathname; which also means the spot where you have get_filename() as a parameter to fm_alert needs to be broken out into a variable so it can be free’d properly as well.